# Bind control's Enable property to a CheckBox's Checked property

Tags: c#, asp.net, bind, checked

I want to set the Enable property of a RequiredFieldValidator control, depending on the Checked property of a CheckBox control. My controls are wrapped in an UpdatePanel. If I write the following code, everything works fine.

ASPX/HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBox 
     ID="chkIsEmailSubscribed" 
     runat="server"
     OnCheckedChanged="chkIsEmailSubscribed_CheckedChanged"
     AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:TextBox 
     ID="txtSubscriptionEmail" 
     runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
     ID="rqrSubscriptionEmail" 
     runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="txtSubscriptionEmail"
     ErrorMessage="Email is required" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void chkIsEmailSubscribed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rqrSubscriptionEmail.Enabled = chkIsEmailSubscribed.Checked;
}
```

But I want to achieve this without writing any code in the code-behind and instead doing it in the HTML. I want to replace my code-behind logic with the following binding expression:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
      ...
      Enabled="<%#chkIsEmailSubscribed.Checked%>" />
```

But this binding expression doesn't work as I expected. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to display the value of `<%#chkIsEmailSubscribed.Checked%>` from your front-end output.